# Illegal mix of collations using a function

Tags: wpdb, collation

I am running into a collation problem when using a function.

My query is this

```
SELECT CONCAT(PERSON.LastName,', ',PERSON.FirstName) AS 'PersonName', 
funcGetStandardValue(PERSON.ProgrammeId) AS Programme 
FROM wp_persons AS PERSON WHERE (funcGetStandardValue(PERSON.ProgrammeId) = 'Programme1' )
```

The function is this

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE theTitle VARCHAR(100);
    SELECT Title INTO theTitle FROM wp_standard_values WHERE SvId = Id;
    RETURN theTitle;
END
```

Both tables (and all varchar columns) concerned (wp_persons and wp_standard_values) have the same collation of utf8mb4_general_ci

The error returned is

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) and
> (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

The error does not occur if I run the sql script in phpmyadmin

Comment: Very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql - basically the solution is to add an explicit collation keyword near each field in your query to "force" the mix of collations to be compatible.

Comment: This looks more like a SQL question than a WordPress question. You might have better luck over on [the DBA stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com).